# Database Error "Error Number: 1054"

Tags: matrix, assets

I have a fairly fresh install of ExpressionEngine 2.7.2 and am having tons of problems with either Assets or Matrix upon saving an entry.  I'm receiving the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'content_type' in 'where clause'
DELETE FROM `exp_assets_selections` WHERE `col_id` = '1' AND `row_id` = 10 AND `content_type` = 'matrix' AND `entry_id` = '4' AND `field_id` = '6'
Filename: third_party/assets/ft.assets.php
Line Number: 1232
```

Both add-ons were freshly installed (no upgrades) and we're using EngineHosting if that matters

Any help would be great!
Brian

Comment: What version of Assets and Matrix do you have installed? Have you check that they are both up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninjaroll,

yeah, until we get Assets 2.2.2 out the door, which should happen any day now, there's an issue with fresh installs of Assets 2.2. If you run the following query, your issue should be fixed.

ALTER TABLE exp_assets_selections ADD COLUMN `content_type` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `element_id`